# PostgreSQL function having parameters is not using existing index

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, sql-execution-plan

I have a PostgreSQL plpgsql function and noticed that it does not use an existing index on the MATERIALIZED VIEW (my_view), it is querying.

The special thing about this function is, that it invokes another function (check_user) passing its parameter v_username. The result is a boolean and dependant on its value the function decides with the case-construct, if the user gets all data from given destination view (my_view) back or a one, which is being joined with another table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function my_view_secured (v_username text)
  RETURNS setof my_view
  LANGUAGE plpgsql stable  
AS 
$function$
declare
  v_show_all boolean := check_user(v_username);
begin
    
CASE 
    WHEN v_show_all then return query select * from my_view;
    WHEN v_show_all = false then return query select st.* from my_view st join other_table st2 on st2.id = st.id;
end case;

end;
$function$
;
```

When executing the both queries defined in the CASE-WHEN part directly / without the function, PostgreSQL is using an existing index and the query is returning data quite fast (50ms).
When invoking this wrapper function (my_view_secured), I assume the index is not used because it takes about 10-20 seconds to return.

`select * from my_view` --takes some ms

vs

`select * from my_view_secured('RETURNS_TRUE')` -- takes 10-20 secs, although same underlying query as the one above

(Maybe it is my DBeaver settings which falsely gives me the impression, that query 1 takes just some ms)

I have read here [PostgreSQL is not using index when passed by param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67997619/postgresql-is-not-using-index-when-passed-by-param), that it is because due to the function parameter, PostgreSQL can not optimize the query. My first attempt was to rewrite this PLPGSQL style of function to a pure SQL-native query, but I struggle to find the correct logic for it.

From client perspective, I simply want to call the function with

```
SELECT .. FROM my_view_secured ('someusername')
```

and the function takes care about the data to be returned (either all or joined, depending on the return value from check_user function call). The index itself is set on an id field which is used by the join.

Does anyone has an idea, how to solve this issue?

**Some additional informations:**

```
PGSQL-Version: 13.6
my_view (MV): 19 million rows (index on id col)
other_table: 60k rows (unique index on id col)


LOAD 'auto_explain';
SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 1;
SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = ON;
SET client_min_messages TO log;
```

1. Query MV directly:

> ```
> explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)  select * from my_view
>
> Seq Scan on my_view  (cost=0.00..598633.52 rows=18902952 width=185) (actual time=0.807..15754.467 rows=18902952 loops=1)
>   Output: <removed>
>   Buffers: shared read=409604
> Planning:
>   Buffers: shared hit=67 read=8
> Planning Time: 2.870 ms
> Execution Time: 16662.400 ms
> ```

2a) Query MV via wrapper function (which returns all data / no join):

> ```
> explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)  select * from my_view_secured ('some_username_returning_all_data') 
>
> Function Scan on my_view_secured  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=3462) (actual time=9006.965..11887.518 rows=18902952 loops=1)
>   Output: <removed>
>   Function Call: my_view_secured('some_username_returning_to_all_data'::text)
>   Buffers: shared hit=174 read=409590, temp read=353030 written=353030
> Planning Time: 0.052 ms
> Execution Time: 13091.509 ms
> ```

2b) Query MV via wrapper function (which returns joined data):

> ```
> explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)  select * from my_view_secured ('some_username_triggering_join') 
>
> Function Scan on my_view_secured  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=3462) (actual time=10183.590..11756.417 rows=8624367 loops=1)
>   Output: <removed>
>   Function Call: my_view_secured('some_username_triggering_join'::text)
>   Buffers: shared hit=126 read=409792, temp read=161138 written=161138
> Planning Time: 0.050 ms
> Execution Time: 12434.169 ms
> ```

Comment: Are you saying you do  `SELECT * FROM my_view_secured($1) WHERE xyz = $2`, and you would expect this to use an index on `my_view.xyz`?

Comment: Kind of. The join itself happens within the function and should be blackbox for the client. In the most simplest form the client is simply doing a SELECT * FROM my_view_secured("some_non_pg_username") from outside (which could have additional non-joint related where clauses etc) and I want the function to join only for particular users (check happens in another function called check_user) but for other users it should simple return the data without a join (select * from..). The index itself is set on an id-field which is used by the join within the function.

Comment: How can this work if the two queries return different numbers of columns?

Comment: @MikeOrganek I guess it's actually `select st.* from …`

Comment: yes indeed (updated it, thanks)

Comment: @AydinK. Oh wait you're complaining that `select st.* from my_view st join other_table st2 on st2.id = st.id` doesn't use the index for the join condtion? Then I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Could you share the query plan for the JOIN statement? That one is missing. And please use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)

Comment: @AydinK.: Are you sure? I don't see any results from the plain query using the join condition. Only a function call. And something else, all execution times are comparable, 12 to 16 seconds. And reading a few GB's from disk will never be fast

Answer (score 1):

I just recreated your scenario and I get index scans for the nested queries as expected. Postgres absolutely **can** use indexes here.

PL/pgSQL handles nested SQL DML statements like this: every statement reached by control is parsed, planned and executed. Since **neither of the two `SELECT` statements involves any parameters**, those plans are saved immediately and reused on repeated execution. Either way, if a plain `select * from my_view;` "uses indexes", exactly the same should be the case for the nested statement.

There must be something going on that is not reflected in your question.

A couple of notes:

- You misunderstood the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67998057/939860). Your case is different as neither query involves parameters to begin with.
- About ...

  > does not use an existing index on the views (my_view), it is querying.

  Maybe just phrased ambiguously, but to be clear: there are no indexes on views. Tables (incl. `MATERIALIZED VIEW`s) can have indexes. A `VIEW` is basically just a stored query with some added secondary settings attached to an empty staging table with rewrite rules. Underlying tables may be indexed.
- **How do you know** the nested queries do *"not use an existing index"* to begin with? It's not trivial to inspect query plans for nested statements like that. See:

  - [Get query plan for SQL statement nested in a PL/pgSQL function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/23355/3684)

It would seem you are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, it is a MATERIALIED VIEW, where the index is set. I've edited the question. The reason why I am doubting an index is used is because I would expect same latency for the non-joined query (meaning: select * from my_view) when querying the MV directly and the wrapper function. But first takes 30ms, latter around 10-20 seconds. I will check the link you provided for getting more information about query plans for nested statements.